# Dagger ObjectGraph Image directory

Tags: android, dagger

In an Android project that uses Maven, How can I see the object graph visually?

I've looked in target/ but I don't seem to find it.

I believe an image is to be created somewhere? Is this right?

BTW this is an android project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there! GraphViz files are placed in the `generated-sources/annotations/` folder inside `target/`.

For example, here is part of the output for one of our apps:

```
$ find . -name *.dot
./common/foo/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/triangle/AndroidModule.dot
./common/bar/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/triangle/AndroidModule.dot
./common/baz/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/triangle/AndroidModule.dot
./triangle/app/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/triangle/AndroidModule.dot
./triangle/app/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/triangle/TriangleModule.dot
```

Comment: Got this in android bootstrap: https://gist.github.com/crised/5729134, No visual representation of this?